# Is accessing different members thread safe in Swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading

I have a class

```
class Foo {
   var bar : Int
   var baz : Int
}
```

I have two threads which both have a reference to the same object of this class. However, they are accessing different members of this class

- Thread 1 is reading and writing to bar.
- Thread 2 is reading and writing to baz.

Is this thread safe?

My assumption that it's, because these two members are different object. However, I want to double check (taking into account my still limited Swift knowledge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if one thread is interacting with one property and another interacting with the other property, and you really having nothing that interacts with both properties, then you'll probably be OK.

Admittedly, it feels like a low [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) solution (should these two properties really be properties of the same class?). Also, it seems a tad fragile (contingent upon the other objects that interacting with this object honor this division of thread integrity), but technically it could work.

If you can give us a practical, real-world example of how you plan on using this, we might be able to offer more concrete counsel.

Comment: yeah. it feels fragile (it's too easy to change some code which will start interacting with another member).

Comment: It's also a possible performance problem. I don't know much about swift data layout but if those two vars end up in the same cache line, your 2 threads will compete for ownership (aka false sharing)